# PHP PDO MYSQL - Easiest way to compare array to query and return an array with results not in result of query?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, compare

In PHP I have a simple array called `$allFiles` like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1.csv
    [1] => test2.csv
    [2] => test3.csv
)
```

In MySQL I have a table that has values like:

```
| ID | PROCESSED |
| 0  | test2.csv |
```

What is the easiest way (Using PDO as a connection method) to compare `$allFiles` to the table and return a new array `$newFiles` that contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1.csv
    [1] => test3.csv
)
```

(these are the files that are not represented in the table in MySQL)

I've been through the manual but cannot seem to find anything that would relate exactly to this, I might have missed something though. Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php ?

Comment: There is no ready-made function to do this. Most of the time, you'll find that there is no out-of-the-box solution to your problem. You'll have to write the code yourself, which isn't too hard: query the DB getting all of the file names, create an array with the results, then get the diff between the array you have, and the query results

Comment: @Sherlock Thanks so much, did not think about it that way as was thinking there was a PDO function for this!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes thanks I thought that this would be the case but was just wondering if PDO does actually cater for this type of functionality, guess not (yet)!

Comment: If the allfiles data is not in the database, you will need to select all processed files from the db, then compare the arrays in php.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity: No, and it never will. PDO's job is to enable you to query a database, not to process data. I'm prepared to bet that there never will be a PDO method called `queryDiffArray` or something

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I like your point here and you are quite correct in saying that... I guess that i'm missing a lot of the fundamentals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ready-made function to do this. Most of the time, you'll find that there is no out-of-the-box solution to your problem. You'll have to write the code yourself, which isn't too hard: query the DB getting all of the file names, create an array with the results, then get the diff between the array you have, and the query results.
A basic example would be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT PROCESSED FROM db.table WHERE PROCESSED IN (?,?,?)');
$stmt->execute($allFiles);
$existing = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    $existing[] = $row->PROCESSED;//construct array containing existing values
$notFound = array_diff($allFiles, $existing);
var_dump($notFound);
```

You could make the query a tad more dynamic, by using the length of the `$allFiles` array, and add `?` placeholders accordingly:

```
$allFiles = array_filter(array_unique($allFiles));//clean array
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($allFiles), '?');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT PROCESSED FROM db.table WHERE PROCESSED IN ('.implode(',', $placeholders).')'
);
//alternative:
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT PROCESSED FROM db.table WHERE PROCESSED IN ('.
    substr(
        str_repeat('?,',count($allFiles)),//repeat ?, as many times as there are values
        0,-1//remove trailing ","
    ).')'
);
$stmt->execute(array_values($allFiles));//better safe than sorry
//rest is the same as before
```

That allows you to process any length of array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, makes perfect sense! Just did something now much like your first example only to see all these answers. Awesome for comparisons sake. I'm toying with your "dynamic" alternative option. Two issues with this, you're missing a comma after: `count($allFiles))`? Second, when i run this i get: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'`. This points to the execute line. A bit confused as the majority of my experience is with Mysqli :)

Comment: @IndigoIdentity: add the comma (was indeed a typo), and as for the fatal error: the `$allFiles` array could be associative, or have non-consecutive indexes (`[0 => '', 2 => '']`), which you could resolve by replacing  `$stmt->execute($allFiles);` with `$stmt->execute(array_values($allFiles));` and perhaps invoking `array_filter` and `array_unique` first, reassigning `$allFiles` to avoid `null` values and duplicates updated that bit in my answer, too

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. With that i figured out what the issue was. When i read the contents of the directory that contains the csv files, i remove "." and "..". The result of this is that the array starts with the key value 2 (as we've taken 2 values out of the array) and this is what made the issue for me. Reindexing them with `array_values()` worked like a charm, thanks so much for all of the input as i feel smarter now!!

Answer (score 2):

PDO returns an array of values from your table. You can check if your results are already in the db array. You can check on array key, if your results are already in the PDO array, skip this result. If your result isn't in the PDO array build a new array with that value or values.

Note: PDO returns an nummeric and text key for one record. When you check if key exist you have to check if your key is a nummeric key. If nummeric, skip that one.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the guys in the comments has said, there is no PDO function that does this outright. You'll have to gather your results first, put them in an array and use `array_diff()`.

Rough example:

```
$allFiles = ['test1.csv', 'test2.csv', 'test3.csv'];

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE', 'username', 'password');
$query = $con->query('SELECT PROCESSED FROM table_name');
$db_results = [];
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $db_results[] = $row['PROCESSED'];
}

$results = array_diff($allFiles, $db_results);
```